# API Android usada para programa que corta músicas

Tags: java, android, api

Qual API Android usar para editar e cortar música? segue um link de um app android que faz isso:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.herman.ringtone&hl=pt_BR

Aguardo.

Comment: O que o link tem a ver com a pergunta?

Comment: Acredito que a segunda foto mostra o requisito dele. Ele quer uma library/API que faça crop de um determinado arquivo de música.

Comment: O link serve para ter uma ideia do que o app faz e é exatamente isso que quero saber.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que terá duas opções que são as mais viáveis, recomendo analisar ambas e verificar qual é a mais recomendada para o seu projeto:

## musicg-api

ótima API porém possui uma limitação séria: só trabalha com arquivos WAV

https://sites.google.com/site/musicgapi/technical-documents/wav-file-format

## ringdroid

Não é uma API e sim uma biblioteca que provavelmente terá o que precisa para o problema descrito.

https://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/